# Spray Json Format

Tags: json, scala, spray, spray-json

So I have the method that returns Future[JsValue]:

```
def foo(): Future[JsValue] = {
 Json toJson Json.obj("name" -> "John","surname" -> "Doe")
}
```

and spray routing that uses it:

```
path("foo") {
 onComplete(foo()) {
  case Success(value) => complete(value)
 }
}
```

What I would want to get on the client is Json:

```
{name: "John", surname:"Doe"}
```

But what I get on the client is an object:

```
Object{fields: [{name: {value: "John"}}, {surname: {value: "Doe"}}]}
```

How do I get the desired Json?

Comment: You are seeing this because the default spray marshaller for `Map[String,String]` does what you observe. If you want `{name: "John", surname:"Doe",foo:"bar"}`, when presented with a general `Map[String,String]`, you will need to write your own marshaller. Alternatively, if you only have names and surnames, can you consider using a case class instead?

Comment: There are more fields but I did create case class. I thought that there are some easier solutions

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
onComplete(foo()) {
  case Success(value) => complete(value.toString)}
```

At least it works for me.